# OpenMP - parallel code has unexpected results

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

```
#include "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include/omp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> lst;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        lst.push_back(i);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<" "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<endl;
    }   
}
```

suppose that I can get this:

```
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  1
```

However, sometimes I can get this result:

```
30  0
1  0
2  0
  1
4  1
```

or even this kind of result:

```
30 1 0
4 1

1 0
2 0
```

I know this is because the output code:

```
cout<<i<<" "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<endl;
```

has been spliced into small segments and has no order when doing output.
But who can tell me how to prevent this from happening?
Thanks.

Comment: *"But who can tell me how to prevent this from happening? "* - don't parallelize it if you want sequential output!

Comment: Anyway, POSIX-compliant `printf` is atomic and so you could use that.

Comment: what if I really need to execute several statements each time? How can I make sure they are not interrupt, and I need them to be running on two-core processor?

Comment: I mean, how to make several statements as an atomic?

Comment: @Terry: Why do you think the `list<int>` is relevant?

Comment: @Terry: You can use locks, or use `#pragma omp atomic` or `#pragma omp critical`.

Comment: @Terry: Why do you use `"/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include/omp.h"` instead of just `<omp.h>`?

Comment: That really helps. Thanks. I used openMP in ubuntu, and only #include<omp.h> doesn't work, so I tried this way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23297/discussion-between-terry-and-phresnel)

Comment: @Terry: I unfortunately lack the time to chat, sorry. But as said, if you are really new to multithreading, it would be best to get an overview about the topic in general (threads, locks, deadlocks and other enemys, mutexes, critical sections, and more)

Comment: You are never supposed to include compiler-specific headers like `omp.h` by their full path. When you give `gcc` the `-fopenmp` option, it automatically includes the correct path to `omp.h` in the search list. If that doesn't work for some reason, then there is a problem with your compiler installation.

Comment: @phresnel, `atomic` is not applicable to statements that constitute pure function calls like `cout << a << b << c`.

Comment: @HristoIliev: True, I misread Terry's query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << i;
        cout << " ";
        cout << omp_get_thread_num();
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Calls to `<<` in the different threads may be executed in any order. For instance `cout << i;` in thread 3 may be followed by `cout << i;` in tread 0 which may be followed by `cout << " ";` in thread 3 etc. resulting in the garbled output `30 ...`.

The correct way is to rewrite the code so that each thread calls `cout <<` only once in the loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << i << " " << omp_get_thread_num() << '\n';
        cout << ss.str();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Standard output streams are NOT synchronized!

The only guarantee the standard gives is that, single characters are outputted atomically.

You need either a lock - which defies the point of parallelization or you could drop the "<< i" which should result in a quasi synchronized behavior.

Comment: can you give more details on how to give it a lock? Thanks.

Comment: @Terry: This wasn't part of the question; you should grab your OpenMP documentation, open up your search engine of choice, and/or study multi threading techniques. If you don't have the slightest clue about multithreading, than please don't (yet); save yourself and your colleagues the pain of debugging parallel code in imperative programming languages.

Comment: Standard output streams are synchronized. Each call to `<<` and `>>` is atomic. The problem is that in the loop there are 4 calls to `<<`.

Comment: @user763305: The standard only guarantees that concurrent calls to operator<< don't lead to a data race (aka you won't corrupt the internal state of the stream). They explicitly mention that preventing interleaved output is up to the user (§27.4.1.4)

Comment: @MFH: operator<< starts by constructing a sentry object (§27.7.3.6.1). With Visual Studio, the sentry constructor locks a mutex that protects the streambuffer. That seems indeed to be allowed but not required by the standard (§27.7.3.4 and note 325).

Comment: @user763305: That may very well be, but the sentry is definitely unlocked after each call of operator<< => you can still easily generate interleaved output... `cout<<i<<" "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<endl;` will create the sentry 3 times, after each destruction of a sentry a thread can jump in and do stuff...

Comment: @MFH: Of course. Each individual call to << is atomic with Visual Studio. This applies by the way not only to the standard streams but to all streams.

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs out of order. This is why you have unordered output.

If your problem is the `30` in

```
30  0
1  0
2  0
 1
4  1
```

then stay cool, there is no `30`, but `3` and `0`. You still have, as expected, an unordered row of `[0..4]`:

```
3 0  0
1  0
2  0
 1
4  1
```

What you can't tell is only which of the `0`s which of the `1`s is not a thread number.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array (of size `5`) containing which thread handled which index and then print it outside the parallel loop.